# How can i select a row in the Kendoui grid depending upon Column value?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have following code:

```
   var newRow = { field: "FirstName ", Value: "" };
   grid.dataSource.add(newRow);
   grid.dataSource.sort({ field: "FirstName", dir: "desc" });
```

which adds a new row at the bottom . Now this row doesnt yet have a uid. I want to select this particular row, how can i do this ?

I try to select by finding the FirstName field as empty string , using the following code

```
     var value = "";
     var row = grid.tbody.find("tr[FirstName='" + value + "']");
     grid.select(row);
```

This does not select the empty row ? How can i select it ?

Comment: According to https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/add , it returns a kendo.data.Model instance. So it does have an uid.

Comment: dataSource.sync(); was the missing thing. I was just using .add .

Comment: @Debbie.S so you resolved this ?

Comment: yes its resolved . how do i mark @GaloisGirls comment / link as the resolution ?